# How to compile Marlin for Melzi board without bootloader?

Tags: marlin, firmware, melzi

I'm trying to enable a lot of features on my custom build of Marlin, and I'm having trouble fitting into a reasonable space limit. I'm compiling through the standard Arduino IDE with Sanguino board set, and I'm barely not fitting -- when I click compile, I get an error informing me my code won't fit.

My understanding is, the IDE is set to assume I'll be uploading through a bootloader, and therefore reserves some space for it. If I'm not planning to use the bootloader, how can I inform the IDE that my program can use more space?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with Visual Studio Code and the PlatformIO plugin? I'm wondering if this expresses the same issue?

Comment: have you looked into compiling into a .hex file and uploading that? You *could* conserve some space by removing unneeded features.